# How does OS manage USB ports?

Tags: windows, linux, usb

If I have a USB printer, how does Linux or Windows manage the device when plugged into a different USB port?  For example, I take a printer plugged into a front USB port on computer and move it to back port; Windows still recognizes that this is a printer already in use by system.

Is this just a special printer setting?  A reason I ask is that I help a friend out with managing a control system (with USB digital I/O).  We had to change computers out and I just plugged the USB ports into random open ports and the program still knew how to find the hardware (remember, entirely different computers)

Answer (score 1):

A USB device sends some data to the host machine called the [device descriptor](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors), which contains identifiers for:

- The vendor of the product
- The product itself
- A serial number for the unit (this doesn't necessarily match the serial number marked on the device's casing)

The serial number is a way for the operating system to know whether it has seen a device before.

Comment: And some devices lack of a serial number explains why they are seen as a new device when plugged into a different port.